# Apache Zeppelin: How to manage dependencies for groovy interpreter

Tags: groovy, apache-zeppelin

I've use [Apache Zeppelin 0.8.1](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/).

I want user [Groovy interpreter](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/interpreter/groovy.html). And use [@Grape](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html) dep menagement:

```groovy
%groovy

@Grapes([
    @Grab('com.github.twosigma.beakerx:beaker-kernel-groovy:0.9.0')
])
import com.twosigma.beakerx.widget.IntSlider
```

But got error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to parse groovy script: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/Ivy
 at org.apache.zeppelin.groovy.GroovyInterpreter.getGroovyScript(GroovyInterpreter.java:140)
```

Reasonable. By official documentation of [Dependency Management for Interpreter](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.1/usage/interpreter/dependency_management.html) I've provide artifact dep: `org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.5.0-rc1`:
[image]

In repositories I have enabled `Central` (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/) which have that artifact:

[image]

But on interpreter restarting and notebook reload I just got error: `Error setting properties for interpreter 'groovy.groovy': Cannot fetch dependencies for org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.5.0-rc1`:
[image]

I have tried (as experiment, not long-term solution) enter into zeppelin `docker container` and download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.5.0-rc1/ivy-2.5.0-rc1.jar into `/zeppelin/interpreter/groovy`, restart interpreter, reload nootebook and it looks like groovy try resolve deps - i see progress-bar for second, but then again got error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to parse groovy script: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: General error during conversion: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: com.github.twosigma.beakerx#beaker-kernel-groovy;0.9.0: not found] java.lang.RuntimeException: Error grabbing Grapes -- [unresolved dependency: com.github.twosigma.beakerx#beaker-kernel-groovy;0.9.0: not found] at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:83) at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.doConstructorInvoke(CachedConstructor.java:77) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrap.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:84) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:247) at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.getDependencies(GrapeIvy.groovy:426) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:169) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:59) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154) at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.resolve(GrapeIvy.groovy:573) at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy$resolve$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:190) at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.resolve(GrapeIvy.groovy:540) at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy$resolve$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154) at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182) at groovy.grape.GrapeIvy.grab(GrapeIvy.groovy:258) at groovy.grape.Grape.grab(Grape.java:167) at groovy.grape.GrabAnnotationTransformation.visit(GrabAnnotationTransformation.java:378) at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:321) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:931) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:593) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569) at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298) at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700) at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:736) at org.apache.zeppelin.groovy.GroovyInterpreter.getGroovyScript(GroovyInterpreter.java:133) at org.apache.zeppelin.groovy.GroovyInterpreter.interpret(GroovyInterpreter.java:155) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:103) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:632) at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188) at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler$JobRunner.run(ParallelScheduler.java:162) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 1 error at org.apache.zeppelin.groovy.GroovyInterpreter.getGroovyScript(GroovyInterpreter.java:140)
```

It looks like groovy does not see repository configurations and try resolve dependencies only locally.

What I should setup to change that?

Comment: Not used Zeppelin for years, but AFAIR you can't use Grab, you have to add dependencies via config https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/usage/interpreter/dependency_management.html

Comment: I link on that documentation from question too. That dependency also did not resolved unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

groovy in zeppelin not designed to support `@Grab`

your artifact is present in a specific repository

http://maven.imagej.net/content/repositories/public/

check this artifact search engine:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.twosigma.beakerx/beaker-kernel-groovy/0.9.0

so, just add a new repo to zeppelin

**UPD:**

for `org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.5.0-rc1` there are a lot of dependencies downloaded
and one of them fails. Here is what I see in console:

```
Error while downloading repos for interpreter group : groovy, 
    go to interpreter setting page click on edit and save it again 
    to make this interpreter work properly: 
         Cannot fetch dependencies for org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.5.0-rc1 
    ...
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException:
    Could not find artifact com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy:jar:0.0.9 in central
    (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
   ...
```

(IHMO it's a bug of zeppelin)

but to make it work set

```
artifact= org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.4.0
exclude=  com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy
```

Comment: Why "org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.5.0-rc1" does not pulled from interpreter settings? It present in central repository. That is first problem.

Comment: And indeed `@Grab('org.knowm.xchart:xchart:3.5.2')
import org.knowm.xchart.*;` work now. You are right about repository. I vote for you question, but it is just a half of answer. And I add it into repositories `http://maven.imagej.net/content/repositories/public/` and still can't get deps.

Comment: what do you see in log when connecting `org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.5.0-rc1` to groovy interpreter ?

Comment: when you set org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.5.0-rc1 dependency for interpreter the full error should appear in console (stdut)

Comment: updated the answer. and it seems in zepelin 0.8.1 problem with logger init

Comment: Why you think problem with logging? And is there workaround for dependencies? `Ivy:2.4.0` also did not loaded

Comment: problem that ivy has a lot of [dependencies](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.4.0/ivy-2.4.0.pom) and one of them `com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy` published not in a standard way check the [url](https://repo1.maven.org/content/repositories/releases/com/jcraft/jsch.agentproxy/0.0.6/) (see the `.` in `jsch.agentproxy` and usualy it's `jsch/agentproxy`). zeppelin can't resolve it. so to make it work set artifact=`org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.4.0` and exclude=`com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy`

Comment: Thank you. Indeed it looks like `zeppelin` bug. And now I be able manage `Grape` dependencies. I have accept answer.